# primefaces datagrid filter by inputtext

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid, filter

I want to use inputtext to filter datagrid.

Some code like this:

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.searchString}">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" update="grid" />
</p:inputText>
<p:dataGrid var="item" value="#{bean.findItemsByName}" columns="9" layout="grid" rows="130" paginator="false" id="grid">
```

Comment: Is this working code?  If so, where is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide the `bean` code?

Comment: Datagrid displays data correctly. I want to update datagrid by using inputtext. It's look like filter datatable, but i want datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There us no built in feature that allows datagrid filtering, but you can code your own.

Something like this (using google library):

Bean:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicates;
import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

//The full list
private List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
//The filtered list
private List<String> filterednames = new ArrayList<String>();
private String filterValue;

public void filterList() {
    List<String> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(
            getNames(), Predicates.containsPattern(filterValue)));

setFilterednames(filteredList);
}
```

HXTML:

```
    <p:inputText value="#{bean.filterValue}">
        <p:ajax event="keyup" update="grid" listener="#{bean.filterList()}" />
    </p:inputText>
    <p:dataGrid var="name" value="#{bean.filterednames}" columns="9" layout="grid" rows="130" paginator="false" id="grid">
           <h:outputText value="#{name}" />
    </p:dataGrid>
```